# How to add offset in list items?

Tags: html, css, razor

I need to add offsets to my list items, but I haven't seen any property that could do that (except marker-offset which is deprecated). In my case I have a method that builds a list recursively, and at each new list I need to add offset.

I use razor views, so I have a method called withing a list:

```
<ul>
   @showMenu(Model, string offset)
</ul> 
@helper showMenu(List<MyViewModel> model){
foreach(var category in Model){
if(category.idParentCategory==0){
   continues; //break point
}
<li>
    @if(category.childCategories.Count()!=0){
    <ul>
       @showMenu(Model, offset) //offset to be changed for next iteration
    </ul>
</li>
```

And here is my viewmodel:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    public long idCategory { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string path{ get; set; }
    public int idParentCategory { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryModel> childCategories { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentModel> childDocuments { get; set; }
}
```

Every category has childCategories / childDocuments. Here is the DocumentModel:

```
public class DocumentModel
{
    public long idDocument { get; set; }
    public long idCategory { get; set; }
    public string docName { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you provide code example from jsfiddle or smth like that?
PS. You can simple add `padding-left: 2px;` to item, it should work.

Comment: Sorry for no example, it's just too many parameters enter in play here, and the question seemed pretty straightforward

Comment: What I didn't realize is that I use div elements and that it changes the appearance of my list (items don't have any offset whereas lists naturally do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For recursive list, just nest the lists.

To add spacing between the marker and the list item using `padding-left` to the `li`.

To add spacing between the marker and the edge of the page use `margin-left` to the `ul`.

```css
ul.class1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.class1 li {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul.class2 {
background-color:green;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.class2 li {
  background-color: blue;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="class1">
  <li> One item </li>
  <li> Two item </li>
  <li> Three item
    <ul class="class2">
      <li> Three sub item 1 </li>
      <li> Three sub item 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Four item </li>
</ul>
```